# selecting a distinct value of column 2 where column one is equal to a certain value

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, web

Basically at current i have some script that allows my users to see all distinct values of 'make' which shows the distinct values of a b c ect. But under each of make there is another column which is models. i would like to be abel to select all distinct values of the models column where the make column is equal to a certain make.

Is this possible? if so if someone could point me in the right direction it would be helpful.

current code as follows:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE make=146";
```

i would like it to

//SELECT ALL DISTINCT VALUES FROM Column_Name2 where Column_Name1=146.

Surely this is possible and i just can't figure out which function i need to solve my solution.

Many Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I SELECT rows with MAX(Column value), DISTINCT by another column in SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612231/how-can-i-select-rows-with-maxcolumn-value-distinct-by-another-column-in-sql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
model
FROM table_name
WHERE make = 146;
```

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with simple `distinct` query, e.g.:

```
select distinct model
from table
where make = '<make>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`SELECT distinct(Column_Name2) FROM table_name WHERE make=146`